# Vue.js browserify Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, vue.js

With almost every npm package that I'm trying to use with `vue.js 1.0` I receive this error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '!!./../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js!./../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=style&index=0!./dashboard.vue' from '/Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/vue-html5-editor/dist'
    at /Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /Users/jamie/Code/forum/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

It drives me nuts! I'm using `vue.js` with `browserify`. Looked everywhere on the web:

https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/240
https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/180
https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/295
https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/163

Nothing seems to work! What am I doing wrong!?

2 packages where I've this problem:

https://github.com/lian-yue/vue-upload-component/ 
https://github.com/PeakTai/vue-html5-editor

My `gulpfile`:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');
require('laravel-elixir-stylus');



    elixir(mix => {
        mix.browserify('main.js');
        mix.styles([
                './node_modules/normalize-css/normalize.css',
                './node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css',
                './node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css',
                ]);
        mix.stylus('app.styl');
    });
```

A solution would really help me out.

--EDIT--

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-browserify-official": "^0.1.3",
    "laravel-elixir-stylus": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-html5-editor": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^2.0.0",
    "normalize-css": "^2.3.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-upload-component": "^2.0.0-beta"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your packages.json file ?

Comment: Yes! Please see my edit.

Comment: Weird.Maybe you could try to install these babel dependencies https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/blob/master/package.json#L38, I'm not sure but seems like the vue-upload-component use ES2015.

Answer (score 2):

Those are `webpack` packages and you are using `browserify`. If you need to use webpack packages you should be using webpack as your bundler.

I did have a go at installing the `vue-upload-component` package to see how easy it would be with `browserify` and `elixir` but it's awkward to say the least. I didn't get it working because it uses babel transforms to compile the vue files, so first you need to pull them in manually and then you would likely need to write an elixir extension to use those transforms to get it to work. Obviously each webpack package will be different so you would need to do that each time you install one, which is hardly convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck changing the configuration output of the Vue component I wanted to use to use `webpack -p` instead of just `webpack`.

I could then take that output without the hot module code and put it through `browserify`:

```
browserify file.js --standalone SomeLibrary > file.browser.js
```

Where `file.js` is the *webpack -p* output, `SomeLibrary` is the name you want on the global window scope from the browserify packaging, and `file.browser.js` is your resultant file to include in your project.